# Argument not sufficiently instantiated

Tags: prolog, instantiation-error

So, I just started with Prolog, and I keep getting this error of Singleton variable (Quo,C) and Argumnets not substantially instantiated.

```
Quo:-
    read(A),
    read(B),
    C is A/B,
    write(C).
```

A simple code for finding the quotient of 2 numbers' division is made here.

Comment: `Quo` is a variable (since it starts with an uppercase letter). It cannot appear as the head of a clause (i.e., the thing that precedes the '`:-`'. Replacing `Quo` -> `quo` should solve your problem.

Comment: Thank you very much! Also thanks for the quick response, had my exam in an hour ;p

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Quo` is a variable (since it starts with an uppercase letter). It cannot appear as the head of a clause (i.e., the thing that precedes the `:-`. Replacing `Quo -> quo` solves your problem.